# Reference (not copy) a class as a member of another Class - Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have the following classes

**The Box Class**

```
var Box = new Class({
    Implements: [Options],
    options: {
        name: 'new',
        weight: 0
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
    },
    getParent: function () {
        return this.options.parent;
    }
});
```

**The Collection Class**

```
var Collection = new Class({
    Implements: [Options],
    options: {
        boxes: []
    },
    boxes: [],
    initialize: function (options) {
        var self = this;
        this.setOptions(options);
        Array.each(this.options.boxes, function (box) {
            self.boxes.push(new Box({
                parent: self,
                name: box.name,
                weight: box.weight
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

I am passing the `Collection` class (as the `parent`) to the Box Class when it is created.

```
var newCollection = new Collection({
    boxes: [
        {
            name: 'A',
            weight: 9
        }, 
        {
            name: 'B',
            weight: 3
        }, 
        {
            name: 'C',
            weight: 2
        }, 
        {
            name: 'D',
            weight: 5
        }, 
        {
            name: 'E',
            weight: 7
        }
    ]
});
```

I want the `parent` in the `Box` class to be a reference to the `Collection` class and not a copy, although It seems that I get a copy of the `newCollection` class each time the `Box` class is created (the length of the boxes is different for each one)

```
Array.each(newCollection.boxes, function (box) {
    console.log('*',box.getParent());
});
```

I am new to mootools and even though I have gone through the documentation, this is the way I ended up writing code. Is there a more accepted coding pattern in mootools by which I can reference the `parent`?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LECh6/1/).

Comment: That's really weird. I'll need to check the mootools source code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to miss. `setOptions` ([docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class.Extras#Options%3asetOptions)) **deep copies** the options object. Just set the `parent` property of your Box after initializing it. I've posted a slightly modified version of your [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/LECh6/3/)

```
Array.each(this.options.boxes, function (box) {
    var nB = new Box({
        name: box.name,
        weight: box.weight
    });
    // Note the difference
    nB.parent = self;
    self.boxes.push(nB);
});
```